# struct sockaddr.sa_data appears to be too small

Tags: c, macos, sockets, networking, sendto

I am doing some interposition in Mac OS X (essentially intercepting C calls) and I noticed that the ping application tries to call the sendto function with an addrlen value of 16.  In sys/socket.h I can see clearly that the sa_data array only holds up to 14 bytes:

```
/*
 * [XSI] Structure used by kernel to store most addresses.
 */
struct sockaddr {
    __uint8_t   sa_len;     /* total length */
    sa_family_t sa_family;  /* [XSI] address family */
    char        sa_data[14];    /* [XSI] addr value (actually larger) */
};
```

It freaks me out that the comment says "actually larger" but there's not much I can do about that.

Anyway, the man page shows the signature for the sendto function looks like this:

```
ssize_t
sendto(int socket,
  const void *buffer,
  size_t length,
  int flags,
  const struct sockaddr *dest_addr,
  socklen_t dest_len);
```

And then the man page specifically calls out what to do if the length value is too long for a message to be delivered atomically.  It ignores the situation where dest_len is larger than what dest_addr.sa_data can hold.

If I try to copy 16 bytes of data into another dest_addr.sa_data from the caller it fails and the application crashes, as it should.  Am I misunderstanding how this field is used?  Why does the comment in the header say "actually larger" but then assigns a fixed size to the array?

Comment: OK, well `sockaddr` is kinda of generic structure and in reality you will pass `sockaddr_in` et al.  If your test crashed are you sure you had the correct address family set? Please post the code you used - or just the relevant bits of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually are supposed to use `struct sockaddr`. It's like `void` in `void *`, a stand-in for the actual `sockaddr_foo` structures.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make a lot more sense now.  How does a function like sendto know which structure to use when it is called?  Does it look at `sa_family` and then choose the right `sockaddr_foo` based on that?  Is there a header file that maps `sa_family` to `sockaddr_foo`?

Comment: I'm going to add a new question for this.  Your answer was just what I needed to start finding the right resources.